# Save image in UIImageView

Tags: xcode, image, uiimageview, imageview

In my app the user can load an image from there gallery and display it in the Image View.

what i want to acomplish is have a button that save the image in the image view and then when i rebuild the app in the

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

have the image load that was saved from the button in the image View

my image view outlet name is UserImageView if that helps

thanks